# Check existence of single role in server 2016 using powershell

Tags: powershell, server, windows-server-2012, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to check if Windows Deployment Services is installed in server 2016 using powershell and then use this condition to do further steps. I've tried using Get-WindowsFeature but it gives the status list of all roles and features. I want a command that checks whether a single role or feature is installed or not.
My intention is to:

```
if(WDS is not installed){
    Install-WindowsFeature -Name WDS }
else
    Do nothing
```

Facing problem in finding out status of WDS role

Comment: You know how to install it, but can't get it? ;) `Get-WindowsFeature -Name WDS | % Installed`  Alternatively: `if (-not (Get-WindowsFeature -Name WDS).Installed) {`

Comment: To add to the comment given by @TheIncorrigible1 (You should make this your answer) and explain how you find out the properties available to you, use this: Get-WindowsFeature -Name WDS | Format-List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to @TheIncorrigible1 and @DavidMartin

Using Get-WindowsFeature -Name WDS | % Installed worked.

Also, Get-WindowsFeature -Name WDS | Format-List helps in finding more helpful details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$FeatureName
)
(get-windowsfeature |where name -eq $FeatureName).Installstate
```

Just pass FeatureName to the the variable